# How to add "directiveResolvers" to apollo-server-express middleware?

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm working on transitioning from apollo-server to apollo-server-express, so that I can implement Stripe webhooks.

Previously with apollo-server, I was able to add `directiveResolvers` to the schema, so that I can perform an `@auth` check on queries or mutations. The server file looked like this:

**apollo-server:**

```ts
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground, ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled } from 'apollo-server-core';
import { CorsOptions } from 'cors';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'graphql-middleware';
import { context } from './context';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import typeDefs from './typeDefs';
import directiveResolvers from '@/directives/isAuthorized';

const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.ORIGIN_URL,
  credentials: true,
} as CorsOptions;

const graphqlEndpoint = 'graphql';

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  directiveResolvers,
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: applyMiddleware(schema),
  context,
  cors: corsOptions,
  introspection: true,
  plugins: [
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled()
      : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()
  ],
  debug: true,
});

server
  .listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 })
  .then(({ url }) => console.log(` Server ready at: ${url}${graphqlEndpoint}`));
```

With apollo-server-express though, I'm struggling to understand where to add these directiveResolvers in the configuration. Here is what the file currently looks like:

**apollo-server-express:**

```ts
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import {
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground,
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled,
  ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer
} from 'apollo-server-core';
import { CorsOptions } from 'cors';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'graphql-middleware';
import { context } from './context';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import typeDefs from './typeDefs';
import directiveResolvers from '@/directives/isAuthorized';

const corsOptions: CorsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.ORIGIN_URL,
  credentials: true,
};

async function startApolloServer () {
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context,
    introspection: true,
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled()
        : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()
    ],
  });
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: corsOptions });
  await new Promise<void>(resolve => httpServer.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }, resolve));
  console.log(` Server ready at: http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
}

startApolloServer();
```

How do I go about adding the `directiveResolvers` to the server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In classic fashion, I figured it out pretty soon after posting this. I'd missed the `makeExecutableSchema` piece that I'd used before. It now looks like this and seems to be functioning correctly:

```ts
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import {
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground,
  ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled,
  ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer
} from 'apollo-server-core';
import { CorsOptions } from 'cors';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { context } from './context';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers';
import typeDefs from './typeDefs';
import directiveResolvers from '@/directives/isAuthorized';

const corsOptions: CorsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.ORIGIN_URL,
  credentials: true,
};

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  directiveResolvers,
});

async function startApolloServer () {
  const app = express();
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context,
    introspection: true,
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? ApolloServerPluginLandingPageDisabled()
        : ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground()
    ],
  });
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: corsOptions });
  await new Promise<void>(resolve => httpServer.listen({ port: process.env.PORT || 4000 }, resolve));
  console.log(` Server ready at: http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`);
}

startApolloServer();
```